# Jar file escapes "--" from substituted variable - Bash

Tags: java, bash, jar

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

MyVariable="--option arg1,arg2"

echo Variable output : $MyVariable
java -jar HelloInternet.jar "$MyVariable"
```

Expected results:

The jar file should recognize and use the value stored in variable.

Actual results:

The jar file escapes "--" from "--option arg1,arg2" , and interprets the variable without the "--" .

Include any error messages:

Exception in thread "main" joptsimple.UnrecognizedOptionException: option arg1,arg2 is not a recognized option

Describe what you have tried:

I tried using `' '` instead of `" "` and vice versa without success.

Comment: I did some tries with a sample jar file which displays its parameters. With `java -jar sample.jar $MyVariable`, I jar file displays 2 parameters "--option" and "arg1,arg2". With `java -jar sample.jar "$MyVariable"`, it displays only one parameter : "--option arg1,arg2". So, I would say that your bash script should use the first approach.

Comment: Concerning the error message that you shared, I believe that the option is correctly passed to your jar file but the latter simply says that it is not part of its expected options.

Comment: setting the var with dbl-quotes is always good. Usually, calling a variable with dbl-quotes is also a good idea, but I think your use case  is an example of when you DON'T want to use dbl-quotes, try just `java ... $MyVariable` . Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an array when you need an array:

```
MyVariable=(--option arg1,arg2)

java -jar HelloInternet.jar "${MyVariable[@]}"
```

Comment: But.... Where can I find a video or site or book to learn about bash? :0